# C# thread safely "refreshing" contents of a concurrentdictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

I'm updating the dictionary using a method which takes in a list. This list contains what should be the updated values stored in the dictionary. For example: I have the values 1,2,3,4 stored in my dictionary. A thread attempts to update the values in the dictionary using the list 0,1,3,5. My "refresh" method within that thread needs to remove 2,4 from the dictionary, and add 0,5.

I'll have multiple threads attempting to do this "refresh" in quick succession, so I want to make sure their operations don't overlap and mess up the dictionary. Because of this, I need each thread which attempts to update the dictionary to complete its operations before moving onto the next thread. I also need to ensure the dictionary is updated in the order the threads attempt to update it.

In my current code, a thread creates a new list, then calls Refresh() to update the dictionary in the SubscriptionCache. I have each thread sleep for a time between 3-8 ms before creating a new list, then refreshing the dictionary using the new list.

Here's a look at my code:

```
public static class SubscriptionCache
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, Subscription> _firstPartySubscriptionIds = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Subscription>();

        //This compares the contents of the dictionary and new list,
        then updates the dictionary accordingly.
        internal static void Refresh(IEnumerable<Subscription> firstPartySubscriptionIds)
        {
          lock(_firstPartySubscriptionIds)
          {
            try
            {
                Compare(firstPartySubscriptionIds, true).ForEach((s) =>
                {
                    var t = _firstPartySubscriptionIds.TryAdd(s.GetHashCode(), s); Print("Added" + s.SystemID + " Success: " + t + " With Key: " + s.GetHashCode());
                });

                Compare(firstPartySubscriptionIds, false).ForEach((s) =>
                {
                    var t = _firstPartySubscriptionIds.TryRemove(s.GetHashCode(), out s); Print("Removed" + s.SystemID + "Success: " + t + " With key: " + s.GetHashCode());
                });


               LastRefreshedOn = DateTime.Now;
            }
            catch { }
          }
        }

        private static List<Subscription> Compare(IEnumerable<Subscription> firstPartySubscriptionIds, bool reverse)
        {
            var masterList = _firstPartySubscriptionIds.Values.ToList();
            var newList = firstPartySubscriptionIds.ToList();
            var returnList = new List<Subscription>();

            if (reverse == false)   // Returns elements in the old list which are NOT in the new list
            {
                foreach (Subscription s in masterList)
                {
                    if (!newList.Contains(s))
                    {
                        returnList.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            else    //Returns elements in the new list which are NOT in the old list
            {
                foreach (Subscription s in newList)
                {
                    if (!masterList.Contains(s))
                    {
                        returnList.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnList;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure simple locking  will cause perfomance problems for you?

Comment: You need to review your code.

Comment: @Evk Now that I'm thinking about it, I don't see how my program could work without it. I can't think of another way this could work conceptually.

Comment: Well question is also if this is a problem. It seems your code does not do any heavy operations inside that potential lock (for example does not call external services\databases) - so there is no problem to just lock anyway.

Comment: @Evk I'm still getting problems after locking the whole code block within Refresh(). That should ensure only one thread can add to the dictionary at a time, but I really need the threads to add to the dictionary in the order they were created.

Comment: Maybe update your question with current code,  including how you use Refresh method + clarify your requirements.

Comment: @Evk I've updated the code, and explanation. I essentially want each thread attempting to refresh my dictionary to refresh in the order they were created. I thought using the lock in Refresh() would accomplish this, but now I'm thinking I may need a queue to store the "refresh lists".

Comment: I carefully read but still don't understand. So you created thread A first, then thread B. Thread A was slow and thread B tries to refresh first. You want it to wait until thread A also calls Refresh, then wait until A competes and only then allow thread B to refresh?

Comment: I'm actually going to use a very different implementation now. Thank you for responding, and helping to the best of your ability.

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentDictionary doesn't just magically make everything involving multiple threads work.  It just makes all of the methods of the structure logically atomic.  If you want to perform multiple operations as a single atomic operation, which you seem to want to do, you'll need to explicitly manage your threads to do that (I.e. by locking).